# Problem with enumitem and \raggedright

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, enumitem

I want my items in lists (`enumerate`, `itemize` and `description`) to be raggedright. So I use `enumitem` package to make things easier

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before = \raggedright}% In fact I use \RaggedRight from ragged2e package, but it doesn't matter (I think)
```

But then I found a problem: if the enumerate is in another paragraph it works great; but if it is in the same, the `\raggedright` applies to the paragraph too.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\raggedright}

\begin{document}
%   THIS WORKS
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{enumerate}

%   THIS DOESN'T
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    \item Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### How can I solve this? Is this a bug?

[image]

**EDIT:**

After reading @egreg 's answer. I'm still not completely pleased because I get two different spacing if I compile this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{before=\csname par\endcsname\raggedright}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{enumerate}\raggedright
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\csname par\endcsname\raggedright}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{enumerate}%\raggedright
    \item Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And I'm not totally convinced that the second one (egreg's one) is right (the space is larger).

Comment: No difference for me: http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/9996/shutterseleo006.png

Comment: @Sigur Even with `article`? What's going on? I don't know why it shows that way to me.

Comment: Yes, the same: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/7355/shutterseleo007.png

Comment: I get exactly the same output as Manuel.

Comment: @Sigur, you don't have it `\raggedright`. I don't know what have you compiled (I didn't realized before).

Comment: I just copied your code and put it on a new file and run `pdflatex` on it.

Comment: But then the `enumitem`'s `\setlist[…]…` configuration didn't work on your document. Ah, may be you copied from the top, which I wrote `\setlist[enumerate]` instead of `\setlist[itemize]`. I'll edit now.

Comment: No problem in my `log` file. I don't know. Sorry. I'm using TeXlive 2011.

Comment: @Jubobs Didn't see that. By the way, I'm interested in using `enumitem` package. Does that work well toguether with the package?

Comment: @Manuel It should work. Try it.

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not sure how to redefine the `enumerate`/`itemize` environments, because I don't know how they are treated by the `enumitem` package.

Comment: I don't expect `\newenvironment{ritemize}{\begin{itemize}\raggedright}{\end{itemize}}` and
`\newenvironment{renumerate}{\begin{enumerate}\raggedright}{\end{enumerate}}` to conflict with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @Jubobs I'm sure it works, but I don't want to create a new environment, just redefine the usual ones (together with the `enumitem` package).

Comment: @Manuel You should follow egreg's guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to solve the issue, which is due to the fact that the second case doesn't end the previous paragraph when `\begin{itemize}` is performed, so the `\raggedright` code influences it:

```
\setlist[itemize]{before=\csname par\endcsname\raggedright,
  partopsep=0pt}
```

In this way we end the paragraph before starting the `itemize` list. The

```
\csname par\endcsname
```

trick is to avoid a spurious error message.

Alternative way. No `before=\raggedright` setting, but

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\preto\item{\raggedright}}
```

Beware that this setting will be inherited by all lists nested to an `itemize` environment.

Comment: But don't I get the `\parskip` space before the list?

Comment: @Manuel Yes. But if you use a non zero parskip, you're doing bad typography. ;-)

Comment: The option does not work for me! Strange. Maybe my package is out of date.

Comment: I use the default one, I think, (which I don't know how much space it is). But I'm (still) not convinced that before the `enumerate` there should be a \parskip. It continues the paragraph before, just in a more *graphical* way. See my edit, I explain my idea a little bit better.

Comment: That worked. By the way, do you think that this should be reported? If this is the expected way of working, I think it's wrong.